# Overflow:auto not working even with height set

Tags: javascript, html, css

While making a website I built an exception holder to the side that stores every exception thrown.

I want to make it scroll as opposed to it expanding the webpage if too many things go wrong.

I am using CSS and `overflow:auto` to alter the `#error` element.

[The website](http://gdriv.es/website-test)

```css
#error {
  color:red;
  display:table;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-color:black;
  height:750px;
  width:10em;
  overflow:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#important{
  vertical-align:top;
  border-collapse:separate;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='error'>
      <div>
        <center>Errors:</center>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td id='important'>
      Everything here is important. Everything. Please wait while we load.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: show the relevant code please

Comment: The code is on the webpage I linked but okay, it was easier to read that way.

Comment: The website is not working @Bast

Comment: @ThomasBormans Oh, let me get a new link for that then.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. Use `text-align: center` instead.

Comment: @Oriol I will fix that later, I needed it for a quick fix before I finished.

Comment: The link is fixed! Edit: Thanks to whoever fixed the code, I have no idea how to use this site that well.

Comment: Remove display:table; from #error and move  id='error' to nested div it will fix the problem <div  id='error'>Errors:...

Comment: @genichm Could you please post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display:table;` from `#error` and move `id='error'` to nested `div`. It will fix the problem.

```css
#error {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-color: black;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#important {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id='error'>
        <center>
          Errors:
          <br/><br/><br/><br/>
          AAA
        </center>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td id='important'>
      Everything here is important. Everything. Please wait while we load.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```